# ToolbarColorScheme change when back to previous screen programmatically using NavigationStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm using navigationStack and I found that when I back programmatically using navigationPath instead of using default back button on navigation bar. My ToolbarColorScheme is change from dark to white.
Here is my demo to reproduce this bug, for some reasone I want to use navigationPath to control app navigation because it's can help me with some case like popToRoot() or pop to exact some screen.
So can anyone can help me with this.
Thank you!

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    
    private var bgColors: [Color] = [ .indigo, .yellow, .green, .orange, .brown ]
    
    @State private var path: [Color] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List(bgColors, id: \.self) { bgColor in
                NavigationLink(value: bgColor) {
                    Text(bgColor.description)
                }
            }
            .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                .blue,
                for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
                VStack {
                    Text("\(path.count), \(path.description)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(path, id: \.self) { color in
                            color
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        path.removeLast()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Back")
                    }
                }
                .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(
                    .blue,
                    for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Color")
        }
    }
}
```

Default state
[image]
When back by press back button
[image]

Comment: Which iOS version you're using? It works fine on iOS 16.4. I think navigationPath did nothing to this.

Comment: I'm runing on 17.0.1 simulator, I think it's because of navigationPath because when I use enviroment dismiss to back, everything is is oke

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out 3 lines from your codes. I guess that would solve your problem.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    private var bgColors: [Color] = [ .indigo, .yellow, .green, .orange, .brown ]
    
    @State private var path: [Color] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List(bgColors, id: \.self) { bgColor in
                NavigationLink(value: bgColor) {
                    Text(bgColor.description)
                }
            }
            .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                .blue,
                for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
                VStack {
                    Text("\(path.count), \(path.description)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(path, id: \.self) { color in
                            color
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        path.removeLast()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Back")
                    }
                }
                //.toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
                //.toolbarBackground(
                //   .blue,
                //   for: .navigationBar)
                //.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Color")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it work but unfortunately that move make the second screen does not have navigationBar color, the thing I want every screen in my app look the same

Comment: That's easy I guess, just create View and modify navigation background from there.

Comment: From where, I'm not really understand, can u show me ur code

Comment: If you mean creating a view in another struct, it still has a same bug